# Bulk Insert avoiding duplicate without using EFCore Extension

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I am new to Entity Framework and EFCore.
So my project requirement is to bulk insert data coming from excel source.
Also I only need to insert non matching columns,
I dont want to use ZZZ project's dll.

Is There any other way of doing it?

**Bulk Insert Code**

```
 public async Task<TimeSpan> BulkInsertDataMatrix(List<DataMatrix> lst)
        {
            try
            {
                Start = DateTime.Now;
                await _appDbContext.BulkInsertAsync(lst);
                TimeSpan = DateTime.Now - Start;

                return TimeSpan;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

**DataMatrix Class**

```
public class DataMatrix
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public int TotalMarks { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Write a SQL Merge statement, and pass a tvp with your data.

Comment: BulkInsertAsync is part of Entity Framework Extensions, have you tried using AddRange or AddRangeAsync instead? They take IEnumerable<TEntity> as a param.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take a look at N.EntityFrameworkCore.Extension. It is a bulk extension framework for EFCore 6 that is available on nuget.org and the source code is available on Github under MIT license.

```
Install-Package N.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/N.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions

Once you install it you can simply use BulkInsert() method directly on the DbContext instance. It support BulkDelete, BulkInsert, BulkMerge and more.

**BulkInsert()**

```
await dbcontext.BulkInsertAsync(lst, 
    new BulkInsertOptions<DataMatrix>() { InsertIfNotExists = true });
```

You can also use BulkMerge to insert or update a large number of entities at once.

**BulkMerge()**

```
await dbcontext.BulkMergeAsync(lst);
```